# Referential Humour: Overuse of demonstrative pronouns and "it"

Tags: discussion

Questions often lose clarity when descriptions include ambiguity which may fail to translate the concept in OP's head to that of a reader. One class of ambiguity concerns demonstrative pronouns ("this", "that", "those", "these") and the ubiquitous "it".

TL;DR: **How do we quickly indicate that a question should replace references with labelled entities?**

In the first sentence you probably easily understood from context "that" means "head" but consider the following part of a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65371158/):

> when the first container is shown, buttons in this container are working perfectly but if other container is shown, buttons in this container don't work. Buttons in this container appear but not functional.

Here, the initial "this" should be clear because there is only one context ("when the first container is shown") but another context is introduced before the second "this" which makes the second and third "this" ambiguous. The intended reading was probably:

> When container A is shown buttons in container A are working perfectly but if container B is shown buttons in container B don't work. Buttons in container B appear but are not functional.

(There is also a temporal dimension in the linked question but that dimension is unnecessary for my question here.)

I cases of ambiguous usage (overuse) of pronouns I want to link to some guide (like [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) that quickly lays out the problem and remedies.

Searching for guides that deal with the use of language are hard to find, the classification "demonstrative pronoun" is effectively not in use, searching for "pronoun" finds too much gendering-related stuff and [searching for "pronouns -gender"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&q=pronouns%20-gender) has nothing relevant.

So how do you relay such a problem (and its remedy) within a single comment?

In the vein of "do not attribute to malice that which can sufficiently be explained by stupidity" I think "do not attribute to stupidity that which can sufficiently be explained by humour" and so think of the problem as "Referential Humour" - basically granting maximum benefit of the doubt while also trying to be funny.

I would almost like to be able to tag a question as "referential-humour" (basically a deficiency tag to allow OP quick access to a guide and make life easier for reviewers) but that feels too imposing - at least before I see some answers here.

Comment: So you want to write a parser for human language? This is how I understand your question right now.

Comment: I want to be able to say something like: "Hey, your question is bad because your entities are badly labelled. Follow this link to see how you can improve your question."

Comment: Yeah, but first you need to find out if there are truly badly labelled entities. You need to recognize entities and then evaluate how bad they are. You need to *understand* the text. These things are already pretty difficult.

Comment: I'm talking about a program that does this.

Comment: We, that is humans, read texts all the time. We are the parsers and easily recognise the feeling of confusion (if not so easily the source). In a case where we can point to things like 30 instances of "this" and state that the intended meaning of these things is unclear we have understood the/a problem, even if the text is not understood.

Comment: Ah, okay, then I agree, that would be hard. I am mentally coming from the realm of reviewing "first questions" and "first answers". So human work not that of a program.

Comment: Creating previously unknown terminology for grammatical issues is not going to work for an international site where English is not the primary language for a significant percentage of users.  Just tell them straight and simple *"your containers explanation is hard to follow which is which"*. Once alerted to any confusion most users are willing to clarify. If it is so abstract as to be impossible to follow....vote to close

Comment: You are suggesting what SO/SE calls a "meta tag", a tag not about what the question is about, and those are to be avoided. There are unlimited problems in unclear writing, not just in details of wording but in organization of ideas; just edit what you can & comment to the author. (Your example repair is readable but could be reasonably described as lacking certain commas or "then"s plus either a comma or semicolon.) A much-used cut & paste comment of mine: 'This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean.'

Comment: **Not a duplicate** The proposed "duplicate" questions supposes strong confidence in understanding a question's intent while my question supposes the opposite - "unclear" question versus unclear question. That said, I am **fine with closing** my question here. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: I do not understand what the distinction is that you are trying to draw. Either a question is unclear to you, or it isn't. You've described one possible reason for ambiguity. That is no different than any of a hundred *other* reasons why a question might be ambiguous and therefore unclear. They should all be handled in the same way: edit to fix the ambiguity if you can fix it; otherwise, vote to close the question as unclear.

Comment: @CodyGray Say a question mentions a button not showing in "the browser". A comment may ask to specify the browser to clarify the question. Why would you want to close such a question as opposed to clarify? Figuring the browser is hard work, we do not want the reader to try that. Writing a comment is (mostly) easy and informs OP. OP adding information they know is easy and informs the reader. It seems fair to make an effort to clarify. I wanted to improve my commenting by asking how people communicate my class of ambiguity (where edit is not an option) quickly to OP.

Comment: If a question is unclear, you should be closing it. You might *also* ask a clarification question in the comments, but that is not something you or anyone else should be doing *instead* of closing.

Comment: @CodyGray You just solved a knot I did not even know I had in my thinking. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I do not think this is a problem that needs solving, as I've yet to see cases where this kind of interpretability has been that much of a problem.

If those questions are really that unclear, they can simply be edited.

Comment: You may well be right. One problem is, that too many references do not allow a reader of the question to edit it because they do not yet know what OP wants. So they need to comment, something like "you are using too man references obfuscating your intent - please label your entities" and then OP needs to edit. I would like a shortcut for the reader but maybe there are only arduous solutions.